# Hide buttons from titlebar in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, window, nswindow, titlebar

The Apples Human Interface Guidelines say:

[macOS Human Interface Guidelines: Panels](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/panels/)

How do I make the very first titlebar in that image (with only a close button). Disabling both *Resize* and *Minimize* in IB only make the resize/minimize buttons get disabled. But I want them to disappear. How can I do that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
[[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton] setHidden:YES];
[[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton] setHidden:YES];
[[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton] setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: And also `[[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton] setHidden:YES];` to hide the close button (if displayed).

Comment: @pkamb Need help to set back in full screen

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for when trying to create an interface like Quicktime player.

Answer (score 12):

Swift code for accepted answer

```
window!.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)!.isHidden = true
window!.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)!.isHidden = true
window!.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)!.isHidden = true
```

Comment: is not working(on xcode 9.2)... the title and the close, miniaturizeButton, fullscreen buttons are still there.

Answer (score 2):

I also needed this but visible for mouse overs - Swift:

```
var trackingTag: NSTrackingRectTag?
override func mouseEntered(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if trackingTag == theEvent.trackingNumber {
        window!.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)!.alphaValue = 1.00
    }
}
override func mouseExited(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if trackingTag == theEvent.trackingNumber {
        window!.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)!.alphaValue = 0.01
    }
}
func updateTrackingAreas(_ establish : Bool) {
    if let tag = trackingTag {
        window!.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)!.removeTrackingRect(tag)
    }
    if establish, let closeButton = window!.standardWindowButton(.closeButton) {
        trackingTag = closeButton.addTrackingRect(closeButton.bounds, owner: self, userData: nil, assumeInside: false)
    }
}
override func windowDidLoad() {
    window!.ignoresMouseEvents = false
    updateTrackingAreas(true)
    window!.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)!.alphaValue = 0.01
}
func windowShouldClose(_ sender: Any) -> Bool {
    window!.ignoresMouseEvents = true
    updateTrackingAreas(false)
    return true
}
```

Visibility is needed but just slightly - 0.01 opacity, to have the tracking area effective.

Answer (score 1):

another way is...

```
for (id subview in [self window].contentView.superview.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSTitlebarContainerView")]) {
        NSView *titlebarView = [subview subviews][0];
        for (id button in titlebarView.subviews) {
            if ([button isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]]) {
                [button setHidden:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer a little bit? I mean why & how it differs.

Comment: @Fawzan, this way can apply to customized title view.