# Closing a Window in Visual Studio for Mac/Xcode

Tags: c#, xcode, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac

I'm a PC guy taking his first shot at Mac.  I'm building a Cocoa desktop app
with Visual Studio for Mac, Xamarin.Mac, Xcode, .Net and C#.

The app consists in a home window with additional windows the user
can select using menu items I added to the standard Mac app menu.

I'd like to close the active window when the user selects a new window.
I can't find the line of code where it says "Open this new window.",
where I could say just before "Close active window". Neither in Visual Studio
nor Xcode. (So far, the interaction Visual Studio-Xcode is a bit of a black box to me.)

So how do you close a window before opening a new one?

And as a bonus question (if I may): how do I get rid of the close-min-max buttons in a
window created from a view controller control.  Easy to do with the home window,
but I haven't found the way to do it in additional windows.

Comment: So to be clear, when they "select"  new window, are they clicking a button or just changing focus?

Comment: As for the bonus question, I've never used Cocoa with C#, but here's how you'd do it in Swift, I'd imagine it's similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/43370575/4700841

Comment: Finally, have you considered using MAUI? I know it's not an answer to your question but it's the new cross-platform .NET UI Framework from MS and it looks pretty sweet

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Persistence.   I'll look into all this.  And to answer your question, the user clicks on an app menu item to open the form related to that menu item.